# Attaching a QLabel to a QLine or QLineF

Tags: c++, qt

Is possible to attach an QLabel to a QLine or QLineF?

```
QLineF incidenceLine;
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, Qt::SolidLine));
incidenceLine.setP1(QPoint(width / 2, height / 2));
incidenceLine.setAngle(qreal(angleOfIncidence) + angleOffset);
incidenceLine.setLength(indexLength);
painter.drawLine(incidenceLine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you can not... you can add a widget to a widget but that is another story...

but you can draw text in the paint method using the painter object:

```
painter.setPen(Qt::yellow); // or another well contrasting color
painter.drawText(x, y, my_text);
```

where x and y are ints to map in the canvas, my_text is the string object